# Lie Derivative of $n$-forms

Tags: differential-geometry

If we have some coordinate system $(x,y,z)$ with $\mathbb{R}^3 =M$ for some manifold $M$ how do we find the Lie derivative of some $$\Lambda=\frac{x+y}{x-y}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$

$1-$form seems to be straight forward with the application of the formula, but $3-$ forms, doesn't seem so obvious. I would appreciate the help.

$$\mathcal L_{X}\bigg(\frac{x+y}{x-y}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\bigg)=\iota_X(d\Lambda)+d\iota_X (\Lambda)$$

First we compute the $d\Lambda$ term which is given by:
$$d\bigg(\frac{x+y}{x-y}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\bigg)=(\phi dx + \psi dy)\wedge dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$
Then just compute the interior product of this differential form for the part $\iota_X(d\Lambda)?$

Comment: Your question looks a bit strange: what do you mean by '$(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ belonging to some manifold $M$'? Unraveled that, for these kind of things Cartan's formula should work.

Comment: I have edited it. I will show what I can do, and perhaps you can check if I am on the right direction?

Comment: I guess you mean that you are working on a manifold, $\mathbb{R}^3$, endowed with coordinate system $(x,y,z)$, which might be the system of Cartesian coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^3$. 
In order to compute the Lie derivative of $\Lambda$ you need to specify a direction $X$ first. Cartan's formula gives: $\mathfrak{L}_X \Lambda = i_X d\Lambda + d(i_X \Lambda)$, where $i_X$ is the contraction with $X$. 
Note: you are working on $\mathbb{R}^3$, so $d\Lambda = 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, is my approach above correct?

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment above, $d\Lambda = 0$. In your question I do not see this (even if it immediately follows from what you write...). This yields $i_X(d\Lambda) = 0$. Then you should compute $d(i_X \Lambda)$.

Comment: OOO yes, so because if I expand $$(\phi dx+\psi dy)\wedge dx \wedge dy \wedge dz=\phi dx\wedge dx \wedge dz\wedge dy\wedge dz+\psi dy\wedge dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=0$$ Where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are just representation of the differential terms of $dx$ and $dy.$